# Project Euler problem 37: truncatable primes

Tags: ruby, primes, project-euler

I am working on [Project Euler problem 37](http://projecteuler.net/problem=37) and I have the following program:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

require 'prime'
h=11
y=0
x=0
while x < 11
    if h.prime? == true
        boo = true
        f=0
        n=h
        c=0
            while n > 0
                f += (n%10) * 10**(10-c)
                n/=10
                boo = false if n.prime? == false && n != 0
                c+=1
            end
            n=h
            c=10
            while c > 0
            n = n % (10**c)
            boo = false if n.prime? == false && n != 0
            c-=1
            end
        f /= 10 while f % 10 == 0
        if boo == true
            y+=h
            x+=1
            p h
        end
    end
h+=2
end
p y
```

It's designed to catch all of the eleven truncatable primes and does a good job of it, it catches the first ten is under one second, but it takes forty-nine seconds to find the last one, which happens to be, admittedly, a much larger number than the rest, is there any way to speed this up so that the eleventh one does not take so much time?

Comment: i dont know any ruby, but i was reading about Truncatable primes and found this post that have 2 different approaches to solver it, maybe it can help you. http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-37-truncatable-primes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some small notes on style:

- `if h.prime? == true` should be `if h.prime?`; never use `method? == true` or `method? == false`, use `if` and `unless`.
- I would replace your `if h.prime?` with `next unless h.prime?` and unindent the entire inner block; I hate having the entire body of your loop wrapped in a single if statement.
- You should really, *really* choose better variable names. Single character names are a terrible practice. This is borderline obfuscated, who wants to figure out what a blob of uncommented difficult to read code does, in order to help you improve its performance?

Here's a simple refactor which is (on my system) 4x faster than your code, mostly because I'm aborting the outer loop early if the first inner `while` fails:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

require 'prime'


h, y, x = 9, 0, 0

while x < 11
  h += 2
  next unless h.prime?

  boo, f, n, c = true, 0, h, 0

  while n > 0
    f += (n % 10) * 10 ** (10 - c)
    n /= 10
    boo = false if !n.prime? && n != 0
    c += 1
  end

  # Don't keep checking if we already know this number fails
  next unless boo

  n = h
  c = 10

  while c > 0
    n %= (10 ** c)
    boo = false if !n.prime? && n != 0
    c-=1
  end

  f /= 10 while f % 10 == 0

  if boo
    y += h
    x += 1
    p h
  end
end

p y
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll improve my use of variable names in the future. You helped me cut down my run time by 75%

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with mathematical/logical problems, you should consider ditching imperative style altogether and use [functional programming](https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming) instead. Ruby is not a functional language, but you can apply a lot of its principles. The point is: describe what you are doing, what values are, not how you get them.

Let's start coding taking the description of the problem, isn't that what you'd like to write?

```
solution = primes.select { |n| truncatable_prime?(n) }.take(11).sum
```

Well, so write it and just fill the blanks. I'd write (Ruby 2.x):

```
require 'prime'

def truncatable_prime?(n)
  if n >= 11
    s = n.to_s # using strings for simplicity
    truncated_left = (0...s.length-1).map { |i| s[0..i] }.map(&:to_i)
    truncated_right = (1...s.length).map { |i| s[i..-1] }.map(&:to_i)
    (truncated_left + truncated_right + [n]).all?(&:prime?)
  else
    false
  end  
end

module Array
  def sum
    reduce(0, :+)
  end
end

primes = Prime.instance.lazy
solution = primes.select { |n| truncatable_prime?(n) }.take(11).sum
#=> 7....7 (in 3.7s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of testing for prime-nes of odd numbers you can just generate primes:

```
require 'prime'
prime_generator = Prime.instance
prime_generator.each do |prime|
  break if prime > 1000
  puts prime #well, do testing for truncatability here
end
```